# WP7 sand physics performance improvement

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7, drawing, game-physics

I'm creating a sand based windows phone 8 game and I'm thinking about ways to boost the performance.

The sand falls from the top and collides with stuff, so it has to be calculated each frame.

The current implementation works like this:

- There's a short[,] array with the pixel information, like this pixel is filled with sand/obstacles/lines
- The sand algorithm is really simple. I move every grain randomly left and right if there's space there and let it fall down if there's space below
- For performance reasons I create a WriteableBitmap with the unchanging background images at the level start
- When I draw the field I copy the pre created WriteableBitmap, add the changing parts to it via WriteableBitmap.Pixels[] and set it as the canvas background via ImageBrush.ImageSource
- What I do on every update is calculating the sand movement in a background thread and let the UI thread do the drawing. 
  That means I go through the whole short[,] array and look if the pixel[] is sand, if yes calculate the grain movement. After that copy it to the background image etc.

With this setup I get around 15 fps in debug mode on a NOKIA Lumia 820, which seems way to slow.

I could of course go for some small optimisations, like using a random map instead of random.Next or using one big short[] instead of short[,], but I commented out different parts of my code and I seem to be missing a major performance sink somewhere in this setup.

Comment: How many FPS do you get without any sand movement (comment out)? Ie is the problem really sand algorithm, or maybe just drawing part?

Comment: That's the strange thing, if I let the background thread sleep(20) each turn, I get 18 fps with movement and if I comment the sand movement out it goes up to 30 fps. But If I set sleep lower like sleep(5), I get 25fps with movement and it breaks down to 0 if I comment it out. The same can happen with sand movement and low sleep values, which is the reason I let it sleep. Hmm now that I type this, this might be because the UI thread gets new draw calls while still handling the old ones? I should look into that.

Comment: The unfinished UI thread was indeed bringing my app down. Now I get up to 21fps with sand movement and without sleep() and up to 33fps without sand movement. I fixed it like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453553/windows-phone-how-to-tell-when-deployment-current-dispatcher-begininvoke-has-co

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to make it so sand that is completely obstructed below/on its sides is set as 'inactive'. Inactive sand is not checked on updates until something moves on its sides/below it (which will set all pixels that are now freed as 'active')

Comment: I thought about that, but with the code like this, it makes no performance difference if I have 50 grains or 500 on the screen, because the "should I move checks" fail so fast.

Answer (score 1):

I started creating something like this myself www.sandicle.com there's an old test video on there, its a bit faster now and has more features... (I always enjoy dropping some lava :)...) hope to get back on this project soon (bit busy at the moment :(

but basically I get 40-60fps by making the resolution smaller

I also added an editor so you can make your own particles and you can download new element packs as people create them :)

Comment: Ah I know that one. :) Yes I already made the resolution just half the screen size, which gave me a big boost, but I can't make it any smaller than that for challenging level design.