# How to access UI thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8, begininvoke

I am trying to access the UI thread in C# for windows phone 8.  So far I got this. However, once it runs `SmartDispatcher`, it jumps to finally with `receipt == null`.

I got the SmartDispatcher class from this website(http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/04/propertychangedbase-crossthread/).  I was wondering if other people had this problem and how to solve it.

```
private async void purchaseProduct()
        {       
            try{
                li = await Store.CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();

                SmartDispatcher.BeginInvoke(async delegate()
                {
                    receipt = await Store.CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(package_id, true);
                });

            }    
            catch 
            { 
                DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR)); 
            }
            finally
            {
                if(receipt != null)
                {
                    parseXML(package_id);
                    prepData();
                    httpPostData();
                    Store.CurrentApp.ReportProductFulfillment(package_id);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it will jump there immediately, as you are commencing an asynchronous operation, which does not block, but returns immediately.
Look, if the object contains a method `Invoke` instead of `BeginInvoke`. `Invoke` will block until the operation is complete.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke) thread as a reference.

Comment: Hi thanks, I found the answer to my problem here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453553/windows-phone-how-to-tell-when-deployment-current-dispatcher-begininvoke-has-co)